# How to set HTTP response header in PHP for JavaScript Fetch API

Tags: javascript, php, fetch-api, http-response-codes

I'm trying to set an `http_response_code();` in `PHP` to fire an according `if-statement` in the `fetch API` response. But the `response.status` in `JavaScript` is always `200 OK`. I'm really stuck with this.

What am I doing wrong?

**Here is the `JavaScript` bit:**

```
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 422) {
          console.log(
            'The upload did not work. Please make sure your files are images and no bigger than 2MB.'
          );
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error: ', error);
      });
  }
```

**And in `PHP`:**

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ) {

    if (isset($_POST['folder'])) {
        $folder = $_POST['folder'];
    } else {
        $folder = 'new-folder';
    }

    if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {

        $errors = [];
        $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/data/uploads/images/' . $folder . "/";

        // if folder does not exist, create it
        if (!file_exists($path)) {
            mkdir($path, 0777, true);
        } else {
            // stuff
        }

        $extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'webp'];
        $pattern = "#^(image/)[^\s\n<]+$#i";
        $all_files = count($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $all_files; $i++) {
            $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
            $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
            $tmp = explode('.', $_FILES['files']['name'][$i]);
            $file_ext = strtolower(end($tmp));
            $file = $path . $file_name;
            $verifyimg = getimagesize($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i]);

            try {

                if(!preg_match($pattern, $verifyimg['mime'])) {
                    throw new Exception("Only image files are allowed!");
                }

              // here goes more validation like this

                if (empty($errors)) {
                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file);
                }

            } catch (Exception $exception) {
                echo $exception->getMessage();

                // Get the current response code and set a new one
                http_response_code(422);

                // Get the new response code
                http_response_code();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce something else must be meddling ... php framework?

Comment: I'm not using a framework. But I added more PHP code.

Comment: if the response code is not in the 2xx or 3xx range then fetch() will reject the promise I think, and so the catch() will run instead of then(). So if you return a 422 code, your `if` statement in the "then" will not run.

Comment: However if you think the issue is that the PHP never goes into the PHP "catch" block, then you'll need to show us what test data you're using, and what debugging you've done, so we can judge whether anything could be going wrong. have you tried to use logging to trace the path your code is taking, for example?

Comment: It goes into the PHP "catch" block. The echo I have in there works. If I `var_dump` `http_response_code`, it returns 422. But if I `console.log` `response.status` in the JS then() block, I always get 200. I will see what putting my `if` in the catch() block does, later. The test data I'm using is an *.mp4, since that would get rejected by my validations (only images allowed). I hope this helps. If not I can provide more code.